# Boost Python and shared_ptr upcast

Tags: c++, python, boost

---

### Sample code for dll/pyd:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public: Base() {}
public: int getValue() { return 1; }
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr;

class ParentA : public Base
{   
public: ParentA() : Base() {}
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<ParentA> ParentAPtr;

class Collector
{
public: Collector() {}
public: void addParent(BasePtr& parent)
{
    std::cout << parent->getValue() << std::endl;
}
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Collector> CollectorPtr;

ParentAPtr createParentA()
{
return ParentAPtr(new ParentA());
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
boost::python::class_<Base, BasePtr, boost::noncopyable>("Base",
        boost::python::no_init)
        .def("getValue", &Base::getValue)
;

boost::python::class_<ParentA, ParentAPtr, boost::python::bases<Base>>("ParentA")
;

boost::python::implicitly_convertible< ParentAPtr, BasePtr >();

boost::python::def("createParentA", createParentA);

boost::python::class_<Collector, CollectorPtr>("Collector")
    .def("addParent", &Collector::addParent)
;
}
```

---

### example code to test it in Python console:

```
import hello
p = hello.createParentA()
c = hello.Collector()
c.addParent(p)
```

---

### Initial post with fake code:

I'm having some problems in having Boost Python to upcast a shared_ptr from Python.

```
class Base() {...};
class ParentA(): public Base {...};
class ParentB(): public Base {...};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Parent> ParentPtr;

class Collector() 
{
  void addParent(BasePtr& parent) {...}
}
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Collector> CollectorPtr;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonModule)
{
 boost::python::class_<Collector, CollectorPtr>("Collector")
  .def("addParent", &Collector::addParent)


 boost::python::class_<Base, BasePtr, boost::noncopyable>("Base", 
            boost::python::no_init)
 ...
 ;

 boost::python::class_<ParentA, ParentAPtr, 
            boost::python::bases<Base>>("ParentA", 
        boost::python::init<>())
 ...
 ;

 boost::python::implicitly_convertible< ParentAPtr, BasePtr >();
}
```

And in Python we do:

```
from PythonModule import *
p = ParentA()
c = Collector()
c.addParent(p) # Fails here because no upcast is happening.
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Compiled on VS2008, with BOOST 1.44 and Python 3.0.

Thanks,

Comment: Since there is at least one typo in the above (ColletorPtr instead of CollectorPtr) it's not the real code. Perhaps that doesn't matter to people who are familiar with Boost's Python binding. But please, post real code to the degree possible -- it helps solving the problems.

Comment: Touche! It's not real code. Its just that it seems so basic that I thought this would simplify the point. If necessary I can post some real code but perhaps not the original due to confidentiality agreements.

Comment: It helps to make sure your sample compiles and exhibits the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... while preparing the real sample code I came out with the solution. The problem is in the Collector.addParent(BasePtr& parent). It seems that Boost Python does not like it to be a reference. Changing it to be Collector.addParent(BasePtr parent) fixes it. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: He he, this is what we like to *say* often happens. And now it happened! :-) Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try Collector.addParent(const BasePtr& parent)